# enable 'sudo' to rm wild repo (gitolite)

Tags: sudo, gitolite, rm

I need to delete wild repo, but don't have enough privileges to do so, even
though I am gitolite admin user, and I have no public key of the CREATOR of
that repo (as it's on another physical machine, which I currently have no
access to). I read something about 'sudo' command, but I don't know where I am
supposed to enable it, and how. I suppose it should be in .gitolite.rc file?!

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `sudo` command (introduced in [gitolite v3.04, 2012-06-27](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/3455375e69ffd357adf96566f79e91407af8b532/CHANGELOG#L129-L141)):

> `sudo` -- allows an admin (i.e., someone who has push rights to the '`gitolite-admin`' repo) to run any remote command as some other user.
>
> This is useful, for example, when a user claims he is unable to access a repo, and you need to check the 'info' output for him, etc. However, it does not work the other way, sorry!

[The source](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/3455375e69ffd357adf96566f79e91407af8b532/src/commands/sudo) includes that way this command is activated, using [`gitolite query-rc` command](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/3455375e69ffd357adf96566f79e91407af8b532/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L366-L371):

```perl
# figure out if the command is allowed from a remote user
gitolite query-rc -q COMMANDS $cmd || die "Command '$cmd' not allowed"
gitolite $cmd "$@"
```

You need to add '`sudo`' to the list of enabled command [in your `.gitolite.rc` on the gitolite server](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/3455375e69ffd357adf96566f79e91407af8b532/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L366-L371).

```perl
ENABLE => [

    # COMMANDS

        # These are the commands enabled by default
        'help',
        'desc',
        'info',
        'perms',
        'writable',

        # Uncomment or add new commands here.
        'sudo',
```

Comment: great! ;) didn't find this in docs, so I wasn't sure where to add it.